# How to avoid hardcoded template name in a django app, integrated with django-cms?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a custom Contact Form App, and I want to integrate it with django-cms. From what I understand I have to register the app with django-cms, and then in my views I have to return a RequestContext instance instead of a regular context instance. So in my `views.py`, I have

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          {'form': form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I don't know if I'm missing something here, but my issue here is that I don't want to hardcode the template name `my_template.html`. Instead, I want the template to be the same one I put when adding a new page, so my question is, is there a way to get the template  from the django-cms page thats hosting the app or do I have to hardcode the template to be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your apphook is a single view mounted on `/`, you can just use `{% extends request.current_page.get_template %}`, however this does not work on subpages in your app.

For that you would need to reverse the root view of your app, use `cms.utils.page_resolver.get_page_from_request` with the `use_path` argument to get the page, then call `get_template` on the page and extend that.